# When do I know I captured the WPA 4 way handshake?

Tags: wpa

When running:

```
airodump-ng --ivs --channel 1 --write output --bssid VV:II:CC:TT:II:MM mon0
```

**Question**: When do I know I captured the WPA 4 way handshake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`airodump-ng` puts the phrase "WPA handshake:" in the upper right hand of the terminal window when it has captured the handshake.

See [this tutorial](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa) for confirmation.